# Zero gradient may not imply the function is constant

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, gradient-descent

Let $f:U\to\mathbb{R}$ where $U$ is an open and connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\nabla f=0$ in $U$. Does it imply the function $f$ is constant in $U$?

I know it is true for a convex $U$, but could not prove neither disprove for an arbitrary open set $U$.

Can some one please help with a counterexample if false.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, Thanks a lot.

Comment: Convexity allows you to use Lagrange's theorem, but is not a necessary condition. If you considerer any point $u \in U$, since $U$ is open, there will be a ball containing only elements of $U$, centered in $u$. Since the ball is convex, you conclude that $f$ will be constant on each of those balls. Being connected now plays an important role...

Comment: Thank you very much.